# Application settings/properties in Xamarin Forms similar to Shared Preferences in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, local-storage

I wish to store settings/properties at the Application level as well as Page wise. In other words, I need different sets of settings which will stay even when the app is restarted. I have considered Application.Current.Properties and [Settings Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings) for Xamarin Forms but they don't seem to provide the same functionality as Shared Preferences in Android, where you can simply pass context and get Preferences for that context. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the settings plugin for Xamarin Forms if you data you want to save does not need securing.

You could create a settings object, serialise and store with a context key if you need to store different preferences per context

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

If it is usernames, passwords or tokens and needs securing one option is the secure storage plugin

https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a local SQLite database to store application settings that persist through app and phone restarts.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Xamarin.Auth. It uses Keychain for iOS and KeyStore for Android to persist data.
"Saved Accounts are uniquely identified using a key composed of the account's Username property and a "Service ID". The "Service ID" is any string that is used when fetching accounts from the store."

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth

Section 4.2 from README file